# Sort NSString objects in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, nsmutablearray, unrecognized-selector

I have NSMutableArray initialised and populated with NSString objects in AppDelegate.m from sqlite database. Now I've setup that AppDelegate in my View Controller :

```
appDelegate = (IBUAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

so I can access my NSMutableArray objects like this:

```
[appDelegate.myNonSortedArray objectAtIndex:row];
```

Now I have created one NSMutable array in my @interface part of my View Controller so I can populate it with sorted NSString objects from my NSMutableArray from AppDelegate.m.

```
@interface IBULanguageViewController ()
{
    IBUAppDelegate *appDelegate;
    NSMutableArray *myArraySorted;
}
@end
```

Then I tried to populate myArraySorted using sorted NSStrings from my NSMutableArray from AppDelegate.m in - (void)viewDidLoad method in my View Controller, so I can access sorted array during creation of cells in my Table View Controller.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    appDelegate = (IBUAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    myArraySorted = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    [myArraySorted addObjectsFromArray:[appDelegate.myNonSortedArray sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)]];
}
```

and I get **[NSNull localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1a51068**.

Comment: One of the 'strings' in your array is in fact an `NSNull` which doesn't respond to the selector (at least that's what the error message says!)

Comment: Yes, that's because some records in database have `null` value. I have got rid of them by using `if(![someRecord isEqualToString:@"(null)"])`, so that I can add `someRecord` to my `NSMutableArray`. As far as I can see there is no `NSNull` in my array. How can I check that?

Comment: If `someRecord` genuinely is an `NSNull` then then that check won't work because `NSNull` doesn't respond to `[someRecord isEqualToString:@"(null)"]` intend to check if the value is an `NSNull` you'd do `if (![someRecord isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]])`. If there aren't too may records then you could log the array to check this, i.e `NSLog (@"unsorted: %@", appDelegate.myNonSortedArray);` the `NSNull`s will be printed (null) to the console (or you could examine the array in the debugger by adding a breakpoint at a relevant location.

Comment: That check doesn't work either because `someRecord` gets populated with `(null)` string value if its value in sqlite database is `null`. If I use `[someRecord isEqualToString:@"(null)"]` and I log it, I can't see any null records. But still I can't sort it. Maybe I need to use some sqlite function?

Comment: The ordering method will work on an NSString @"(null)" because that responds to `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:`. It won't work on an NSNull, and that is what it isn't being called on. You may not want @"(null)" in your array but that won't stop it working. Any instance of NSNull needs to be removed from the array `appDelegate.myNonSortedArray` before you call `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` on it. If they've all been removed then you won't get this error message.

Comment: Please check your nonSortedArray or query for fetching the records from SQLite that it is populating the records or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are have `NSNull`s in your unsorted array. you need to remove these before calling `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` in fact everything in your array must implement the selector `localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:` (pretty much must be a string). You can check that everything responds to the selector by going through the array first and calling `[obj repsondsToSelector:@selector (localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:]` anything that doesn't respond to this will break the sorting method.

Comment: Yes, and I have removed all NSNull objects by using `[appDelegate.myUnsortedArray removeObjectIdenticalTo:[NSNull null]];`,and `sortedArrayUsingSelector:` now works.